# Segmentation fault while freeing memory

Tags: c

I wish to implement a web socket handshake and for that I am using the following code snippet.
But I get segmentation fault when I start freeing the memory which I allocate dynamically. Error shows up in the place where I use free function for the first time. Please help.

```
char rbuf[656];        
char handshake[800];
char *handshake_part2, *handshake_part3,*key,*magic,*final;
unsigned char hash [20];

key=strndup(rbuf+359, 24);     
magic = malloc(strlen("258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")+2);
strcpy(magic,"258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
final = malloc (60);
final = strcat(key,magic);   
SHA1(final,strlen(final),hash);
base64(hash, sizeof(hash));
handshake_part2= malloc(400);
handshake_part2= base64(hash, sizeof(hash));
strcpy (handshake,"HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\nUpgrade: Websocket\r   \nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: ");
strcat(handshake,handshake_part2);
handshake_part3= malloc(400);
handshake_part3="\r\nWebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:9605\r\nWebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:9609/\r\n\r\n";
strcat(handshake,handshake_part3);
printf("Response Header :\n%s", handshake);

free(handshake_part3);
handshake_part3=NULL;
printf("Free 1");
free(handshake_part2);
handshake_part2=NULL;
printf("Free 2");
free(final);`
final=NULL;
printf("Free 3");
free(magic);
magic=NULL;
printf("Free 4");
free(key);
```

Comment: You need to check if the memory was allocated in the first place by checking the value of handshake_part3 after the malloc call:

Comment: Why did you `malloc` in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reassigning `handshake_part3` to be the constant string `"\r\n..."`; did you mean to `strcpy()` (preferably `strncpy()` or equivalent!) this in instead?

Answer (score 2):

You're freeing a constant string.  The memory is leaking because after you call malloc, you assign the constant string (and the malloc'd memory is leaked).

Answer (score 1):

```
handshake_part3= malloc(400); 
handshake_part3="\r\nWebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:9605\r\nWebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:9609/\r\n\r\n";
```

You assign a string literal to `handshake_part3`, and then try to free it... This causes the mallocated buffer to leak, and your `free` to crash. You should `strcpy` that string literal to the allocated buffer, or avoid the allocation and the freeing.

Comment: Clearly, avoiding the allocation is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
final = malloc (60);
final = strcat(key,magic);
```

what you do is you abandon the newly allocated `final` and override it with a `key`'s address. later on you delete it twice (once via `final` and than via `key`), which is not allowed.

That's the only thing I noticed at a glance but I have a feeling there may be more...

**Edit:** And looking at other answers I can see there are indeed "more"

Comment: How should it be then ?
Dint get you completely.

Comment: I'm not sure from your code that you quite understand memory management in C - you have a number of places where you `malloc` some memory and then immediately overwrite the returned pointer with something else (`final`, `handshake_part2`, `handshake_part3`). What do you think is happening when you do `final = strcat(key, magic)`?

Comment: strcat here appends magic to key assigning null character at last and removing from end of key. Destination is returned. 
So it assigns final same as key if I am not wrong.

Comment: Your understanding of `strcat` is correct... so why did you do the `malloc`?